# How can I download a csv file in rails app to my /downloads folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

In my rails app, I have a csv file I created that I'd like to download onto the computer. From other answers it seems that this is the solution:

```
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") {|csv| h.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem} }
```

Running this downloads the csv file onto the root of my app, not similar in how files normally get downloaded. Would this be because I am in development and not production

I have also seen people using

```
file = CSV.generate {|csv| h.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem} }
send_data file
```

but that just gives me an undefined method 'send_data', I'm guessing this method no longer exists for CSV in ruby.

Comment: `send_data` is a controller method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a controller method that responds to the csv file request. Like www.blah.blaah/downloads/data.csv

`respond_to do |format|`

```
 `format.csv`
```

`end`

Remember that you also need to have a view file named data.csv.erb